# Попытка загрузка библиотеки, или проверка на загруженность

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, pinvoke, interop

Что лучше делать с самого начала, проверить загружен ли модуль в память процесса, или попытаться его загрузить, словить ошибку через `GetLastError`, проверить ее значение, и в случае если библиотека уже загружена вызвать `GetModuleHandle`, или сделать все наоборот?

Т.е. примерно так, но не только проверять на `IntPtr.Zero` а еще проверить `LastError` на совпадение с кодом ошибки (*номер кода ошибки пока не знаю поэтому там нет данной проверки*)?

Хотя если модуль был загружен то `LoadLibrary` возвращает его `Handle` а не бросает ошибку, что странно.

```
internal static class WinApi
{
    internal static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr moduleHandle)
    {
        return FreeLibraryEx(moduleHandle);
    }

    internal static TDelegateType GetProcDelegate<TDelegateType>(IntPtr moduleHandle, string procName)
        where TDelegateType : Delegate
    {
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegateType>(GetProcAddressEx(moduleHandle, procName));
    }

    internal static SafeLibrary LoadLibrary(string modulePath)
    {
        IntPtr result = LoadLibraryEx(modulePath);
        if (result == IntPtr.Zero && (result = GetModuleHandleEx(Path.GetFileName(modulePath))) == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        return result;
    }

    #region Private native Methods

    [DllImport(Libraries.Kernel32, SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string modulePath);

    [DllImport(Libraries.Kernel32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary",
        SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool FreeLibraryEx(IntPtr moduleHandle);

    [DllImport(Libraries.Kernel32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress",
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddressEx(IntPtr moduleHandle, string procedureName);

    [DllImport(Libraries.Kernel32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true,
        EntryPoint = "GetModuleHandle")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandleEx(string moduleName);

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В случае использования атрибута *DllImport* и модификатора *extern* для вызываемой функции из внешнего модуля необходимость в указанных вами проверках нулевая, если же вы собираетесь вызывать методы посредством делегатов, то лучше реализовать в своем коде класс *SafeLibraryHandle* на подобие того, как это сделано в самой платформе *.NET Framework*. В результате проверить был ли загружен модуль или нет можно будет с помощью свойства *IsInvalid*. Чтобы было понятней:

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SafeLibrary {
  [SecurityCritical]
  internal sealed class SafeLibraryHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid {
    internal SafeLibraryHandle() : base(true) {}

    [SecurityCritical]
    override protected Boolean ReleaseHandle() {
      return NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(handle);
    }
  }

  internal static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern SafeLibraryHandle LoadLibrary(String lpLibFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean FreeLibrary(IntPtr hLibModule);
  }

  internal sealed class Program {
    static void Main() {
      SafeLibraryHandle slh = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("some.dll");
      if (slh.IsInvalid) {
        Console.WriteLine("IsInvalid: {0} IsClosed: {1}", slh.IsInvalid, slh.IsClosed);
        // return;
      }
      slh.Dispose();
      Console.WriteLine("IsInvalid: {0} IsClosed: {1}", slh.IsInvalid, slh.IsClosed);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Каким образом происходит каст, или маршаллинг от `IntPtr` к `SafeLibraryHandle` ?

Comment: @LLENN, берем в руки _ILDasm_, открываем _mscorlib.dll_ и вперед, к _SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid_. Ну или просто можете заглянуть в исходники _.NET_, чтобы проследить всю цепочку.

Answer (score 1):

> Хотя если модуль был загружен то LoadLibrary возвращает его Handle а не бросает ошибку, что странно

На самом деле, в этом нет ничего странного. Загрузка DLL в Windows спроектирована так, чтобы два куска кода в одном процессе могли независимо друг от друга использовать одну и ту же библиотеку. Когда вы вызываете LoadLibrary и библиотека уже загружена, она не просто возвращает дескриптор, а еще и увеличивает счетчик ссылок для этой библиотеки. Последующий вызов FreeLibrary не выгрузит библиотеку сразу, а уменьшит счетчик ссылок, и выгрузит ее только когда счетчик ссылок достигнет нуля. О каком-то "коде ошибки" в данном случае речи не идет, это абсолютно штатная ситуация.

При обычном использовании функций LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress нет особой необходимости задумываться, загружена ли уже библиотека или нет. Если нужно именно проверить, загружена ли библиотека (например, в целях отладки), функция GetModuleHandle подходит: она для незагруженного модуля вернет NULL и GetLastError будет равно 0x0000007E (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND).